# Why won't an array pass with axios.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, stripe-payments

I'm trying to pass an array with ids to a backend in node.js. When console.log(Products) run before the axios.post(), the Products array has two ids in it. When I console.log(req.body.products) in my backend, the array is empty. How can I still access the array in my backend?

Frontend code

```
const Products = []

                        tempProd.forEach((item) => {
                            firebase.firestore().collection('products').where('name', '==', item.name).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                    Products.push({
                                        price: doc.data().priceID,
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })

                        console.log(Products)

                            axios.post('https://Kvam-E-sport-API.olsendaniel04.repl.co/invoice', {
                                products: Products,
                                cus_id: response.data.medlem.id,
                            }).then((response) => {
                                console.log(response)
                            })
```

Backend code

```
app.post('/invoice', cors(), async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body)
      subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        collection_method: 'send_invoice',
        customer: req.body.cus_id,
        items: req.body.products,
        days_until_due: 14,
      })

    res.json({
      subscription: subscription
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are using a body parser? for example.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Yes, I do use bodyparser

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the request from the network tab in the dev tools? to see if the data is sent in the first place, if the data is sent correctly from the front-end then it's a backend issue.

Comment: Problem got fixed. Just added a timeout to ```axios.post()```